# Changing a HTML element at a certain time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was not able to find a way to make an indicator to indicate that my support team is online. I want the code to be in HTML, CSS, And JAVASCRIPT. The following HTML and CSS is what I have so far. I just need help with the javascript. I want the "Open" HTML and CSS to show from 8 AM - 10 PM. I then want the "Closed" HTML and CSS to show from 10 PM - 8 AM.

"Open" code:

```html
<dvi class="open-circle"></dvi>
<p class="open-p">We are open until 10 PM</p>
```

```css
.open-circle {
  height: 1.5625rem;
  width: 1.5625rem;
  background-color: #00BF13;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.open-p {
  color: #00BF13;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8rem;
}
```

"Closed" code:

```html
<dvi class="closed-circle"></dvi>
<p class="closed-p">We are closed until 8 AM</p>
```

```css
.closed-circle {
  height: 1.5625rem;
  width: 1.5625rem;
  background-color: #ea001d;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.closed-p {
  color: #ea001d;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8rem;
}
```

Comment: You could use Date.now() to find the current time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
<p id="message"></p>
```

```js
var messageElement = document.getElementById("message");
var circleElement = document.getElementById("circle");

const refreshStatus = () => {
    // Set the current time
    let currentDate = new Date().getHours();
    // If the time is between 8 am and 10 pm
    if (currentDate >= 8 && currentDate <= 22) {
      // Change text and add styles
      messageElement.innerHTML = "We are open until 10 PM";
      circleElement.className = 'open-circle';
      messageElement.className = 'open-p';
  } else { 
      // 23 pm to 7 am
      messageElement.innerHTML = "We are closed until 8 AM";
      circleElement.className = 'closed-circle';
      messageElement.className = 'closed-p';
  }
}

// run when starting
refreshStatus();

// updates every 8 seconds
setInterval(refreshStatus, 8000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/03crtha6/

Answer (score 0):

You should get your hands dirty with some `javascript`.

```js
var shopState = document.getElementById('shop-state');

function changeState(){
  var hour = new Date().getHours();
  if (hour >= 22)
  {
    shopState.innerHTML = "We are closed until 8AM";
  }
  else
  {
    shopState.innerHTML = "We are open till 10PM";
  }
  // Check the state after every minute.
  setInterval(changeState, 60*1000)
}
changeState()
```

```html
<div id="shop-state">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `new Date().getHours()` to get current hours and apply a class to show/hide appropriate elements

```js
const hours = new Date().getHours();
document.body.classList.toggle("open", hours > 7 && hours < 22);
```

```css
.open-circle {
  height: 1.5625rem;
  width: 1.5625rem;
  background-color: #00BF13;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.open-p {
  color: #00BF13;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8rem;
}

.closed-circle {
  height: 1.5625rem;
  width: 1.5625rem;
  background-color: #ea001d;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.closed-p {
  color: #ea001d;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8rem;
}

/* added */
body.open .closed-circle,
body.open .closed-p,
body:not(.open) .open-circle,
body:not(.open) .open-p
{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="open-circle"></div>
<p class="open-p">We are open until 10 PM</p>

<div class="closed-circle"></div>
<p class="closed-p">We are closed until 8 AM</p>
```

P.S.
It's `<div>` not `<dvi>`

Comment: Thanks for the response. (Lol I must have been mixed up with dvi and div. thanks for the notice! )

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this will be to execute a function that reads the current hour and check whether its between 8 and 22 (8AM and 10PM). If the condition satisfies, make the open restaurant div visible, or make the closed restaurant div visible.

This function execution must be done in a `setInterval` aswell. This is to ensure that the time update makes the open and closed toggle possible. I have used an interval or 1 minute.

```js
const openNode = document.getElementById('restaurant-open');
const closedNode = document.getElementById('restaurant-closed');
function checkRestaurantTimings() {
    /* 8 AM - 10 PM Open*/
    /* 10 PM - 8 AM Closed*/
    const hoursNow = new Date().getHours();
    if (hoursNow >= 8 && hoursNow < 22) {
        // Time between 8AM and 10PM
        // Open
        openNode.style.display = 'block';
        closedNode.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        // Time between 10PM and 8AM
        // Closed
        closedNode.style.display = 'block';
        openNode.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
checkRestaurantTimings();
setInterval(() => {
    checkRestaurantTimings();
}, 60000)
```

```css
.open-circle {
    height: 1.5625rem;
    width: 1.5625rem;
    background-color: #00BF13;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.open-p {
    color: #00BF13;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 8rem;
}

.closed-circle {
    height: 1.5625rem;
    width: 1.5625rem;
    background-color: #ea001d;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.closed-p {
    color: #ea001d;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 8rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="restaurant-open">
    <div class="open-circle"></div>
    <p class="open-p">We are open until 10 PM</p>
</div>
<div id="restaurant-closed">
    <div class="closed-circle"></div>
    <p class="closed-p">We are closed until 8 AM</p>
</div>
```